# zend framework default actions on a segment route

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I'm following the [zend framework 'album' tutorial](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html)

i want to create the equivalent of the album segment route, mine looks like this:

```
'testimonial' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/testimonial[/][:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Testimonial',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
```

according to the docs, this should point to my testimonial controller, this should map the controller like this:

```
/testimonial points to index
/testimonial/add points to add
```

so in my controller i have the following for testing purposes:

```
class TestimonialController extends \Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
         die('list');
    }

 public function addAction()
    {
         die('create');
    }
}
```

however if i visit the route /testimonial or testimonial/add it doesn't hit either of my debug statements, nor am i presented with any errors, i just get the blank zend skeleton template.

is there something extra i need to do for the route to map? or have i done something wrong so far?

just to be clear, if i add a **__construct** method to the testimonial controller, it hits it correctly, so the controller works and the route knows its there, it just needs to be told to goto **indexAction()** or **addAction()** somehow.

Comment: Did you check your error logs?

Comment: i have `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set("display_errors", 1);` set in index.php and the log displays no errors

Comment: I think it's the action regex under the options > constraints. Change it to this - `'action' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',`

Comment: no difference, still no error but not going to where it should

Comment: Did you forget to add the default action? In the route config? I think the album tutorial has this set to index.

Comment: Also, did you add this controller to the invokables? Which you will find in module.config.php, it sorta looks like this: `'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Testimonial' => 'Application\Controller\TestimonialController',
        ),
    ),` --> I'll make an answer for that if it's not clear

Comment: default action as index doesn't make a difference, and my invokables are already as you say, i believe the __construct wouldnt work if it was wrong

Comment: You're right the default shouldn't make any difference, it should default to index, but misconfiguration could cause it not to. I see now what you meant with the construct, you meant if you hit /testimonial a die in the construct would show? In that case sorry, you did add it to the invokables, my bad ;) Did you try a Literal route? What about conflicting routes (did you try and add this rout to the bottom of the routes config) ? ( **Edit:** By the way, the rest of the route and controller config look normal, I do not think the issue is in either of those )

Comment: i appreciate the help erm, if i change it to literal i get The requested URL could not be matched by routing i imagine because of [/][:action][/:id]. theres no duplicate routes i dont think, i cant see any difference in what im doing that the tutorials do

Comment: Yes, just changing it to literal won't work, you'd have to remove the constraints, and of course the segments ( [] ): `'testimonial' => array(
             'type'    => 'literal',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/testimonial',
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Testimonial',
                 ),
             ),
         ),`. And yes like I said, I think it's not the configuration you've shown above. It's probably a configuration elsewhere. Can you share the rest of the code? maybe a Repo?

Comment: sure @JaapMoolenaar try here https://github.com/gardni/zend-skeleton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `parent::setEventManager($events);` to the `setEventManager()` method in the `TestimonialController`. The AbstractActionController uses this for a few events ( like onBootstrap ) as well.

Changing the method to this works:

```
public function setEventManager(\Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface $events)
{
    parent::setEventManager($events);

    $this->events = $events;
    $events->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'checkOptions'), 10);
}
```

---

You have another small bug in the `getTestimonialTable()` method, you try to get the property `$this->$testimonialTable` which should be `$this->testimonialTable`, like so:

```
public function getTestimonialTable()
{
    if (!$this->testimonialTable) {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $this->testimonialTable = $sm->get('Application\Models\TestimonialTable');
    }

    return $this->testimonialTable;
}
```

---

I hope this helps. sorry for the lengthy commentary session on your question. As it turns out all the code you posted was solid gold ;-)